# Display Issues during install

Tags: display, system-installation

I am trying to replace my old install of Mint14 with a newer Linux distro. I have tried Lubuntu 14.04, Xubuntu 14.04 and SolydX May-14. However they all are having display issues, even from the LiveCD so I cannot even try to install them Images attached:

[image]
[image]

Note: During the LiveCD boot, the splash screens display fine. The issue begins when the desktop shows.

So far I have only managed to have SolydX Jan-14 work and install, however after upgrading the packages, nothing works and I get errors. Images attached:

[image]

As you can see, I cannot even log out!

The reason I have tried these particular distros is because I want to be able to leave it on for a long time without constantly having to wipe and reinstall with each new release.

The machine is a Toshiba Tecra A4 with an 800MHz Centrino CPU, Nvidia 6600 GPU and 512MB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It's the NVidia graphics drivers, I've had this happen to me.  When the computer boots like that, you might be able to use CTRL+ALT+F1 to get to a terminal.  You can alternatively boot into "Rescue mode" so it throws you into a root terminal.

After you're logged in, there is information here that may help you with installing the proprietary NVidia drivers for your particular card.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Edit: I just thought I would mention that if you are concerned with having to reformat to upgrade, Ubuntu and most Ubuntu/Debian based distributions support upgrading in place without reformatting.  The Ubuntu LTS releases or Debian stable are good choices for not having to format because they receive support for long periods of time.

Comment: I looked into the nVidia driver and replaced it as per the instructions for Debian (since SolydX Jan-14 is the only one I can see the interface to install and its based on Debian) but now I get a blank screen instead of a slow system or F'd-up desktop (as photographed above). I can still CTRL+ALT+F1 and get a terminal to enter commands! I do believe you are on the right track, it's just finding the one setting to make it work right. I also noticed that when I ran the upgrade for SolydX, it changed the kernel from 3.11 to 3.13. Not sure if it is a conflict between the driver and the new kernel?